# how to declare static method declaration for selenium? in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

> Below is my code for my login page, I want  to make these methods in
>   Class Login_page, @staticmethod, I tried to do it by adding the
>   @staticmethod syntax , but the problem is , after that i cant access
>   self.driver in the static methods and could'nt find the element for
>   username and password , i am new to programming , any idea what are
>   the necessary changes i should make , to make them static? Sorry if i missed anything stupid!!

```
class Login_page():

    """Initiating class"""""

    def __init__(self, driver):
     self.driver = driver

    @staticmethod
    def Enter_username(self,username):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("usernameId_new").send_keys(username)

    @staticmethod
    def Enter_password(self, password):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("passwordId_new").send_keys(password)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)

    @staticmethod
    def Click_submit(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
```

Comment: Why do you want to mark the methods as `@staticmethod`?

Comment: @DebanjanB  Thanks for the reply back , actually I have shown my code to my teacher and he suggested me to use static methods for  login functionality because its quite generic thing to use, Frankly speaking I am clueless about this staticmethod ...why he suggested that? when we should use staticmethod? why should we use staticmethod? and how does it make any difference , if my code is already working and when we can already call these methods anywhere in the code by their instances what does static make difference. Thanks